# Pytorch Set value for Tensor with index tensor

Tags: python, pytorch

Suppose i have a 2d index Array of shape [B,1,N,2] i.e N points holding indexes on a target tensor of size [B,1,H,W].
what is the best way to assign value to all the indices in the tensor?

for example:

```
for b in batchsize:
  for i in N: 
    target[b,0,ind[i,0],ind[i,1]] = 1
```

but not in loop form
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we look at this setup, you have a tensor `target` shaped `(b, 1, h, w)` and a tensor containing indices `ind`, shaped `(b, 1, N, 2)`. You want to assign `1` to the `N` points *per* batch given by the two coordinates in `ind`.

The way I see it you could use [`torch.scatter_`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.scatter_.html#torch.Tensor.scatter_). We will stick with a 3D tensor since axis=1 is unused. Given a 3D tensor and argument `value=1` and `dim=1`, `.scatter_` operates on the `input` tensor as so:

```
input[i][index[i][j]] = 1
```

This does not exactly fit your setting since what would wish for is rather

```
input[i][index1[i][j]][index2[i][j]] = 1
```

In order to use `scatter` you could flatten `target` and unfold the values in `ind` accordingly.

---

Let's take an example:

```
>>> target = torch.zeros(2, 1, 10, 10)
>>> ind = torch.tensor([[[[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]]],
                        [[[1, 2], [3, 4], [7, 8]]]])
tensor([[[[0, 0],
          [1, 1],
          [2, 2]]],


        [[[1, 2],
          [3, 0],
          [4, 2]]]])
```

We will start by splitting `ind` into `x`s and `y`s coordinates:

```
>>> x, y = ind[..., 0], ind[..., 1]
```

Unfold and reshape them:

```
>>> z = x*target.size(-1) + y
tensor([[[ 0,  4,  8]],

        [[ 5,  9, 14]]])
```

Flatten `target`:

```
>>> t = target.flatten(2)
tensor([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Then scatter the `1`s:

```
>>> t.scatter_(dim=2, index=z, value=1)
tensor([[[1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]],

        [[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]]])
```

And finally reshape back to the original shape:

```
>>> t.reshape_as(target)
tensor([[[[1., 0., 0.],
          [0., 1., 0.],
          [0., 0., 1.],
          [0., 0., 0.],
          [0., 0., 0.]]],

        [[[0., 0., 0.],
          [0., 0., 1.],
          [0., 0., 0.],
          [1., 0., 0.],
          [0., 0., 1.]]]])
```

---

In summary:

```
>>> x, y = ind[..., 0], ind[..., 1]
>>> z = x*target.size(-1) + y
>>> target.flatten(2).scatter_(dim=2, index=z, value=1).reshape_as(target)
```

This last line will mutate `target`.

Answer (score -1):

It's a bit hard to tell what you mean by "a 2D array of shape [B,1,N,2]" (that looks like a 4D array in commonly used notation). But it looks like across all elements in the batch, you want to assign the same values on dimensions 2 and 3 to each element indexed by N. You can use list indexing notation:

```
# assuming ind is a list of tuples of (dim2 index, dim3 index)

# unzip ind such that each resulting list contains indices along a single dimension
dim2_indices = [item[0] for item in ind]
dim3_indices = [item[1] for item in ind]
target[:,0,dim2,dim3] = 1
```